# Javascript WW2 Flag Stars

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble and have been stuck on this program for a while. Basically I need to use for loops in order to make the stars in a flag on the webpage. The order is 48 stars going 8 across and 6 down. My pseudocode is

```
class WW2Flag
    main()
    //Declarations//
        str j
        str x
    for j = 1 to 6
        for x = 1 to 8 step 1
        output "x " 
    endfor
    output break
endClass
```

My program that I have currently is

```
var row = "&#10029";
var x = 48;


for (x=0;x<8;x+1){
    document.getElementById("stars").innerHTML += row;
    if (x==8){
    break;
    document.write("&#10029");
    }
    else {
    j = 0;j<6;j + 1;
    document.write("&#10029");
    }
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to nest your column loop within your row loop, like this.

```js
var stars = [], star = '&#10029';
for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
 for (var j=0; j<8; j++) {
  stars.push(star);
 }
 stars.push('<br />\n');
}
document.getElementById('stars').innerHTML = stars.join('');
```

```html
<div id="stars"></div>
```